# Search for links with RegEx and modify/append (javascript)

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href=”www.test1.com”>consectetur adipiscing 
elit</a>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco <a 
href=”www.test1.com/go/green”>laboris</a> nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse 
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est <a href=” 
www.test1.com/go/red”>laborum.</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I am struggling to write a jvascript code which when executed it finds all links on the page which contain ‘/go/’ and appends ‘-aw’ text to them so they look like this:
• www.test1.com/go/green-aw
• www.test1.com/go/red-aw

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    ?????????
    ?????????
    ?????????
}
</script>
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Please add [mcve] of the code you have so far and explain the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegEx isn't called for here. `querySelectorAll` supports searching within attributes:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="/go/"]').forEach(a => a.href += '-aw');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this.Simply with `forEach` .Then validate the `href` contains `go` text using `/\/go\//` regex

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(a){
a.href =a.href.match(/\/go\//) ? a.href+'-aw' : a.href;
console.log(a.href)
})
```

```html
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="www.test1.com">consectetur adipiscing 
elit</a>, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco <a href="www.test1.com/go/green">laboris</a> nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit
  in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est <a href="www.test1.com/go/red">laborum.</a></p>
```

Comment: Your expression matches any `g` or `o` following a slash. `www.test1.com/oxxxx`.

Comment: Now your expression matches any `go` anywhere in the url. `www.testgo.com`

Comment: Now the expression meets the requirements! I'd still say it's not really an expression, as such. You're just searching for an exact phrase, which can be achieved easily with `indexOf`. If there was something like a case sensitivity check, I'd buy the use of regex, but then that's not what was asked for.

Comment: @DavidHedlund ..Oh really..For *`which can be achieved easily with indexOf`*  => Are you see the question of OP *`Search for links with **RegEx** and modify/append (javascript)`*.

Comment: Yes. I maintain that this is not a job for regex, because the target search phrase does not require an expression. OP appears to agree as my answer is accepted. It is not the asker's job to have the answers.